# Error al importar base de datos en Mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: Error al importar BD en MySql]

Este error me da al importar una base de datos desde phpMyAdmin.

El archivo es .sql (bastante grande, 8 MB) y sí me lo importo pero me muestra este error al final del proceso de importación.

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este tema?

Comment: y que tipo de archivo estas importando?? pq segun el error no esta ejecutando un sql valido...

Comment: En la imagen no parece que estes tratando de importar una BD, parece que recibes el query desde tus input.

Answer (score 1):

Elimina todo lo que no sean sentencias SQL como bien ha dicho el compañero las etiquetas html no son reconocidas por el motor de base de datos.

> No se bien que estas importando, pero el codigo es html por mas que la extension sea .sql (tenes hasta una etiqueta img con class)

[Importar/exportar .sql](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/import-export-mysql-database-command-line/)

Answer (score 0):

No se bien que estas importando, pero el codigo es html por mas que la extension sea .sql (tenes hasta una etiqueta img con class).

El error esta en la linea 1, por lo que el archivo arranca de una mal, el problema que tenes es que lo que estas queriendo importar no responde a la sintaxis SQL(osea no es un SQL).

Fijate si las primeras lineas esta contaminadas con HTML, talvez por algun motivos las querys estan mas abajo, si es asi, borra todo lo HTML que haya y proba, pero me la juego a que todo el archivo esta en HTML.

¿Me podes contar para que queres importar esta BD y de donde obtuviste los archivos a ver si te puedo dar una mejro ayuda?

Comment: Gracias , ya lo solucione elimine todo el html y se exporto perfecto , era un backup de una BD de un Moodle !

Answer (score -1):

El archivo es un bd de un moodle , estoy cambiando de servidor de hosting y tengo que migrar la BD. Al final del archivo .sql si tiene html mas precisamente esto

```
<!-- PMA-SQL-ERROR -->
<div class="error"><h1>Error</h1>
```

**consulta SQL:**
 Editar

SHOW  TABLE  STATUS  FROM  `iltcar_campus`  LIKE  'mdl_log_display'

**MySQL ha dicho:**

## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away